# What could be causing the poor performance (MSE) of a dense neural network on a real time-series dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, python, time-series

I am trying to understand time series analysis and actually I am following the course "Sequences, Time Series and Prediction" in Coursera. The course is based on a synthetic dataset, arguably complex, that is studied with different network configurations. The difference among the various networks architectures exist but within certain range. Roughly, all the architectures succeed to grasp the pattern, and they are more or less precise in describing the spikes of the data proposed.

The last exercise is with real data (sunspots) and propose a complex model including convolutional, recurrent and dense layers.

I added a trial applying only dense networks (very successful on the synthetic data), but it did not work at all. The performance is assesed by the mean squared error, and it is three times bigger with the feed forward network than with the other model including recurrent and convolution layers.
As there are many details, it is difficult to present all them in text format, and to show them all the notebook with the data and the code comparing both proposals (and also using or not a crafted callbacks) is [here](https://github.com/HermesMG/HermesMG/blob/main/hmg_C4_W4_Lab_2_Sunspots.ipynb).

I wonder if I had done any mistake when coding, or if there is another reason for obtaining these results.
Any clarification will be well received.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "it did not work at all"? What does that mean? How are you assessing the performance of this fully connected neural network? You probably should also describe your real data and the hyper-parameters of the model and training procedure. Which algorithm are you using to train the model? How are you training the model? How big is the dataset? How are you testing the dataset?

Comment: I edited the question in order to clarify, as suggested by @nbro. The algortithm, and all the details about the data, the training and the evaluation are in the notebook.

Comment: Thanks for providing these clarifications. I've also changed the title to be what I think is your actual question. Make sure that's the case.

Comment: This title is ok